# Sending data from processing to arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I have problem to send data from processing to arduino mega.

**Processing Code :**

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;

void setup()
{
println(Serial.list());
String arduinoPort = Serial.list()[0];
myPort = new Serial(this, arduinoPort, 9600)
}

void draw()
{
byte a= 3;
myPort.write(char(a));
}
```

**Arduino Code :**

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Servo myservo1;
Servo myservo2;

void setup()
{ 
Serial.begin(9600);
myservo1.attach(9);  
myservo2.attach(10);
myservo1.write(90);
myservo2.write(90);

}

void loop()
{

if(Serial.available()>0){
myservo1.write(70);
myservo2.write(70);

}

}
```

Code is really simple, processing send a value to trigger arduino mega turning 2 servo 
motors.

But it doesn't response at all..
Please help if anyone has any clue.

Thanks :))

Comment: Some things to try: 1) Send the output from Processing to a terminal to check that Processing does what you think it should do. 2) Send the "correct" text to the Arduino from a terminal to check whether correct text will cause the proper response. 3) Put one or more LEDs on your board and light them when significant things happen such as receiving _any_ text, attempting to control the motors, etc. 4) Keep on testing smaller and smaller parts of the system until you identify something that behaves differently than you intended it to. Fix that and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! Finally I realized its because I didnt add delay after every time sending data to arduino..